# insert a row into a sql table from a number greater than 1 and increment all contents of column in following rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm quite new to sql.  I am using a mysql db with opensource cms.  I want to insert a row into the zone table which has all of the locale names stored inside.
I want to insert a row at position 3561, and increment the value of zone id for all of the following rows.  Can you help?

Also, if you know of any good tutorial resources that you could recommend and perhaps a decent online reference (both free please - I'm skint) then I'd be grateful.

Cheers

Comment: The online reference is called "the manual": http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html

Comment: Btw: there is no such thing as "position 3561" in a relational table. Rows in a table ***are not ordered***

Comment: What's the structure of the zone table? (Please add that to your post.) What do the table's contents look like presently and what should they look like after the insert? (Again, please incorporate the samples into your post, thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this.  The `zone_id` should be an id in the zone table that serves no purpose other than identifying the row in the table.  Generally, these are auto-incremented ids that simply add 1 to the previous largest id.

You can insert, delete, and modify the rows in the zone table.  The id will always refer to the same row.  This helps ensure relational integrity.  So, you can refer to a row in the table using the id, rather than some other feature that might get updated.

If, for some reason, you need to output the rows in the table with a sequential id, there are ways to do this in most databases, including MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I received an answer from the opencart forum and it seems there is a php function to achieve this built into the admin.